# grails Link not working in Internet explorer

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I have a button named `Cancel`, when some body clicks on it, I take him to some action of a controller in grails. The button and link look like this..

```
<g:link action="show"><button class="btn" type="button"><g:message   code="default.button.cancel.label" default="Cancel" /></button></g:link>
```

It is working perfectly in chrome but not working in Internet Explorer. IE treat the button as without link. I am wondering why this is occuring ?

Comment: What is the html generated? And what version of IE?

Comment: Why wrap a button in a link ? Can't you just add `class="btn"` in `g:link` and don't add a button ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have two object that handle click one in another.

The button must not be in a link. I suggest you that you drop your button tag and add the `btn` class to the link (bootstrap style) :

```
<g:link class="btn" action="show"><g:message   code="default.button.cancel.label" default="Cancel" /></g:link>
```